# fusioncharts version 3.3.1 Zoomline chart toolText

Tags: fusioncharts

I have licenced version of fusion charts version 3.3.1.
   I have created one zoom line chart. but it does not display toolText on mouse Over of Dataplot.
   can anyone tell me how can i get Tool Text working in this version of fusion charts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To display toolText on mouse over of dataplot, data has to be passed in Standard format for Flash ZoomLine chart. If you are rendering ZoomLine chart in JavaScript mode,  cross-hair has been implemented, which will depict showValues inorder to improve the performance and does not support toolText attribute.

Comment: i am rendering chart in javascript. is there any possibility to show tooltext?

Comment: do i need to upgrde version or any solution?

Comment: Are you not able to see anything when you hover over data plots or you are able to see the values but not the customized tool text? JavaScript variant of Zoom Line chart does not support "toolText" attribute and hence, it is not possible to provide customized tool tips.

Comment: yes, i can see my Dataplot values on hover of Dataplot. but i am notable to customize it.

Comment: JS variant of ZoomLine chart does not support toolText and it will display only dataplot values while hovering over dataplots.

Comment: can we customize CSS of Data plot values which comes in hover of Dataplot?

Comment: No, it is not possible to customize data plot values for JS variant of Zoomline chart.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of FusionCharts - 3.6.0 supports tooltip on mouse over on data plot. You can see it working and the tutorial here. http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-chart-guide-zoom-line-chart-configuring-a-zoom-line-chart.html